# I couldn't find error reason

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to create a simple blog in symfony2 . But unfortunately I'm having a problem while trying to create a form in symfony2 the code is below

```php
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: kanat
 * Date: 2/13/16
 * Time: 8:11 PM
 */
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class EnquiryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('subject');
        $builder->add('body', 'textarea');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact';
    }
}
```

which situated Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\EnquiryType.php
the error is :

> Expected argument of type "string", >"Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\EnquiryType" given

I have no idea how to fix that . Please help me

Comment: You should show the stack trace of the error. Here is nothing wrong with this form.

Comment: CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException: "Expected argument of type "string", "Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\EnquiryType" given" at /home/kanat/Public/Blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 64

Comment: Pass EnquiryType:class to the createForm method of the controller instead of an Instance.

Comment: Албетте @ImanaliMamadiev    !  `public function contactAction()
    {
        $enquiry = new Enquiry();
        $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
   
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_contact'));
            }
        }
        return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:contact.html.twig', array( 'form' => $form->createView() ));
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version, but error:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $yourEntity);
```

You must use:

```
$form = $this->createForm(EnquiryType::class, $yourEntity);
```

**Controller**:

```
public function contactAction() {
    $enquiry = new Enquiry();
    $form = $this->createForm(EnquiryType::class, $enquiry);
```